# Stripe propagate paymentIntent description to Connected Account's transfer payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I successfully created payment intents from a customer's card paying to a Standard Connected account using destination charge. In that payment intent created, I am specifying a description:

```
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculate_payment_amount(duration_minutes),
    customer: "somet id",
    currency: "usd",
    description: `chat duration: 100`,
    payment_method: paymentMethods.data[0].id,
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    off_session: true,
    confirm: true,
    application_fee_amount: calculate_fee_amount(duration_minutes),
    transfer_data: {
      destination: "standard connected account ID",
    },
    metadata: {
      metadata: "something
    },
  });
```

This payment displays the description if I view it from my platform's dashboard.

[image]

But if the standard connected account were to view this payment, the user won't be able to see the description (the same payment viewed from the standard account):

[image]

Is it possible to pass or propagate the same description of the payment intent to the same payment of the standard connected account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's currently possible to propagate the PaymentIntent description when creating destination charges. You would need to manually update the payment on the connected account with the description:

To do so, first, create the payment intent like you are doing now, except save the description as a standalone variable:

```
  const paymentDescription = `chat duration: 100`;
  const connectedAccountId = "acct_xyz";
  
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculate_payment_amount(duration_minutes),
    customer: "somet id",
    currency: "usd",
    description: paymentDescription,
    payment_method: paymentMethods.data[0].id,
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    off_session: true,
    confirm: true,
    application_fee_amount: calculate_fee_amount(duration_minutes),
    transfer_data: {
      destination: connectedAccountId,
    },
    metadata: {
      metadata: "something
    },
  });
```

Then, after the payment is confirmed, get the payment resulting from the transfer to the connected account:

```
  const transfers = await stripe.transfers.list({
    destination: connectedAccountId,
    transfer_group: paymentIntent.transfer_group,
  });

  const paymentId = transfers.data[0].destination_payment;
```

The key above is that when you do a destination charge, Stripe will create a transfer and a payment (in the form of a Charge) to the connected account in the background. Here we're getting the transfer associated with the payment intent, and from that getting the associated payment. This is the `py_xyz` ID that you see when viewing the payment in the connected account's dashboard.

Then, update the payment to include the description:

```
  const updatedPayment = await stripe.charges.update(
    paymentId,
    {
      description: paymentDescription,
    },
    {
      stripeAccount: connectedAccountId,
    }
  );
```

At that point the description will show in the standard account's payment view:

[image]

Comment: This helped me immensely thanks for the question and answer! For those who stumble onto this and are working on a different language such as Python the param name is different e.g. stripeAccount becomes stripe_account.
The connected account ID is also a must, you can refer to the authorisation docs here https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header